# Unmounted setState warning even though the component is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

In my ReactJS@15 project I got a problem with the **unmount setState change warning**, but component is already mounted.

This is the application structure:

```
/app
  /container
     /veil
     /router
        /routed-view
        /other-routed-view
```

Also I have a "**veil manager class**" which triggers a "**_toggle**" event attached to the veil component in this way:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    VeilManager.i().on('toggle', this._toggle.bind(this));
}

_toggle(payload = {})
{
    const { veil = false, cb } = payload;
    this.setState({ isOpen: veil }, cb);
}
```

And from routed-view I trigger following code:

```
componentDidMount()
{
   VeilManager.i().toggle(this._otherFunc.bind(this));
}
```

On debugging flow, Veil component is flagged as unmounted when event is triggered, but has no sense at all, cause container has already being registered with its children.

Even more, Veil component react as expected, so when VeilManager status change Veil toggles in & out.

Any suggestion?

**Extended code**:

```
// Veil.js
import { background, logo, veil }   from './Styles';
import React, { Component }         from 'react';
import VeilManager                  from './Manager';


export default class Veil extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        VeilManager.i().on('toggle', this._toggle.bind(this));
    }

    _toggle(payload = {})
    {
        const { veil = false, cb } = payload;
        this.setState({ isOpen: veil }, cb);
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    render()
    {
        const { isOpen = false } = this.state;

        return (
            <div style={veil(isOpen)} className="veil-wrapper">
                <div style={logo} className="veil-wrapper__logo"/>
                <div style={background}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
// VeilManager.js
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

/**
 * VeilManager singleton reference
 * @type {null}
 */
let $iManager = null;

/**
 * Handles the status of veil
 * @class   veil.Manager
 * @extends EventEmitter
 */
export default class Manager extends EventEmitter
{
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    /**
     * Toggles "isOpen" status
     * @param   {null|Function} cb  To execute after toggling
     */
    toggle(cb = null)
    {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        this.emit('toggle', { veil: this.isOpen, cb });
    }

    /**
     * Returns the singleton instance of VeilManager
     * @return {null|Manager}   Singleton instance
     */
    static i()
    {
        $iManager = $iManager || new Manager();

        return $iManager;
    }
}
```

```
//Container.js
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-css-effects/slide.css';
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-default.css';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch }  from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component }         from 'react';
import Alert                        from 'react-s-alert';
import Aside                        from '@/components/Aside';
import Header                       from '@/components/Header';
import token                        from '@/orm/Token';
import Sidebar                      from '@/components/Sidebar';
import Veil                         from '@/components/Veil';

// VIEWS
import Clients              from '../../views/Clients/';
import Dashboard            from '@/views/Dashboard';

export default class Full extends Component
{
    /**
     * @override
     */
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Header />
                <div className="app-body">
                    <Sidebar {...this.props}/>
                    <main className="main">
                        <Veil/>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            { token.hasExpired()
                                ? <Redirect to="/login"/>
                                : <Switch>
                                    <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                                    <Route path="/clients" name="Clients" component={Clients}/>
                                    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
                                </Switch>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <Aside />
                </div>
                <Alert stack={{ limit : 3 }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
//Clients.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import onFetch              from '@/mixins/on-fetch';

/**
 * Clients view.
 */
export default class ClientsIndex extends Component
{
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this._onFetch = onFetch;
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this._onFetch();
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <div className="row">
                  ...
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
//mixin/on-fetch
import VeilManager from '@/components/Veil/Manager';

export default (cb = null) => {
    debugger;
    VeilManager.i().toggle(cb);
};
```

Comment: The update could be bubbling and causing a high up component to refresh meaning that the setstate is now invalid as its the previous unmounted component

Comment: This looks like case of bubbling, could you provide more code.

Comment: But Veil component stands alone and container component don't share its status with neither its children or the Veil itself.
Also children don't share state upwards.

Comment: @DarpanRangari added extra code

Comment: @ArturoMartínezDíaz not state, *bubbling*. Events in the DOM bubble upwards from child to parent, React does not change that. You can also set it to false if you use the `CustomEvent` constructor. Also, how are you using EventEmitter in the browser?

Comment: @JaredSmith webpack :-)
Changed to dispatchEvent/addEventListener with CustomEvent and stills triggers warning.

Comment: @ArturoMartínezDíaz did you set `bubbles` to `false`? Or call `stopPropagation` in the handler?

Comment: Thanks to all. Solution has being added to description.

Comment: @ArturoMartínezDíaz you can post the solution as an answer and accept that answer to make sure that others who search for this issue are able to see what worked at a glance.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how this site works. Your solution is available in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57786738/revisions) if you'd like to transfer it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**:

As pointed in comments was a problem of bubbling events and state propagation.

Changes made:

```
// Veil manager
...
toggle(cb = null)
{
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    const detail = { veil: this.isOpen, cb };
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('veil-toggle', { bubbles: false, detail }));
}
...
```

```
// Veil
...
/**
 * @override
 */
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        open: false
    };
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
componentWillReceiveProps(next)
{
    const open = next && !!next.open;
    this.setState({ open });
}

/**
 * @override
 */
render()
{
    return (
        <div style={veil(this.state.open)} className="veil-wrapper">
            <div style={logo} className="veil-wrapper__logo"/>
            <div style={background}/>
        </div>
    );
}
...
```

```
// Container
...
componentDidMount()
{
    window.addEventListener('veil-toggle', this._toggleVeil.bind(this));
}

_toggleVeil(e)
{
   this.setState({ veil: e.detail.veil }, e.detail.cb);
}

render()
{
    ...
    <Veil open={this.state.veil}/>
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code above, if the veilManager triggers 'toggle' event after the Veil component is unmounted, then you will face this error.

You can solve it in two ways:

1. Remove the 'onToggle' listener in componentWillUnmount, so that if Veil component is unmounted, there is no need to run its handler.
2. Or, you can keep a variable this.mountedState in VeilComponent and create a separate setStateSafe method which checks for mountedState before calling setState.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.mountedState = true;
        VeilManager.i().on('toggle', this._toggle.bind(this));
    }

    _toggle(payload = {}) {
        const { veil = false, cb } = payload;
        this.setStateSafe({ isOpen: veil }, cb);
    }

    setStateSafe(nextState, cb) {
        if(this.stateMounted) {
             this.setState(nextState, cb);
        }
    }
```

I would suggest option 1, as we should not be calling toggle handler for a component which is unmounted. Thanks